# How can I mate the black king in 4 moves or less (helpmate)

Tags: problems, checkmate, puzzles

In this helpmate puzzle, it is White to move.

[image]

Comment: Did you try putting it in an engine?

Comment: Is there a reason why you expect to be able mate the black king in four moves or less? e.g. is this a helpmate puzzle? If so, the question could benefit from adding that.

Comment: @Chessanator I've edited the question to mention that it's a helpmate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fun problem. White mates with 1.Ke3 Qg4 2.Kf2 (where the king goes doesn't matter) 2...Kg6 3.Ne5+ Kh5 4.hxg4#.